# Encrypting a chat messenger

Tags: php

I'm building a chat messenger for my college project, and I have it working but my next part of this project is too encrypt it so that two users traffic is secure. This app that i'm building is going to be on a personal Linux sever so I have full control over it.

So when two users create an account they will be able to chat to each other over the Internet and their traffic will be encrypted. My understanding of this is when two users start a session a key will be created I understand how encryption works in terms of asymmetric encryption public private key but my issue here is i don't know where to start in terms of coding it out .

I'm looking for some good advice in terms of what way to go about this if anyone has done this I would be so grateful if anyone can push me in the right direction thanks.

Comment: Are you looking to save the contents of the chat into a database or other type of storage? If so, then you need to worry about string encryption, otherwise, like @Dagon said, SSL should be more than enough

Comment: I'm looking to save the messages into a database but want the messages to be secure over the Internet public private key encryption so when two users are speaking to each other their conversations are private so just wondering how to approach that thanks